# Is it possible to dynamically create checkbox and specify itsgroupbox/grid and location in C# only?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I am trying to create a large number of checkboxes and felt it would not be efficient if I created them in the xaml.

Is it possible to dynamically create checkboxes and specify the group box/grid and its location in C# only? I know we can dynamically create the check boxes but I am not too sure how to manage its location via c#.

I am relatively new to WPF, thanks!

Comment: You need to use an `ItemsControl`. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: What do you mean by "not efficient"?

Answer (score 2):

@user2584960 "Once I created them, how can I reference them? I am stuck... I gave the checkbox a name before adding to children but cannot reference them... "

I can only imaging you're trying to do:

```
Checkbox c = panel.Children.Add(new Checkbox());
```

You're not returning anything when you add to the panel, so you cant "Reference" a checkbox class.

As @Alex G was saying, his answer is showing how you add to the content window if you need to set a refrence just create a new class then add it to the window:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
this.Content = panel;
CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
c.IsChecked = true;
//you Could create a loop to loop all of the list checkboxes to add them. 
panel.Children.Add(c);
```

Comment: Sorry @Petter, I don't fully understand how my answer is not an attempt "at answering the question"

Answer (score 0):

most likely you have a Page that has Content property
you should be able to do following

```
            StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
            this.Content = panel;
            panel.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
            panel.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
            panel.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
```

I guess you can reference them as following

```
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            panel.Children.Add(cb);
```

Comment: Once I created them, how can I reference them? I am stuck... I gave the checkbox a name before adding to children but cannot reference them...

Comment: usually memory objects like CheckBox can be referenced with its name. Do you mean referencing it from a different scope?

Comment: The problem is that I use C# to create the checkbox using the new operator. I then dynamically name it based on my iterators value, say at a given moment, my i = 7. then I name my checkbox A :  A.name = "DEFAULT_BOX_" + i (covert to string).   Then in my C# code, how can i reference it again?

Comment: may be you want to keep the list of all the checkboxes at the class level, so you can reference it later on from any scope of the class?